# Display image with css when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to display an image along with some css when 'Blue' is clicked in this fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/C6Ssa/25/

But the image is not being displayed and the css is not being applied ?

Comment: Others have stated the right answer, but you should also consider chaining your function calls. Your `red()` function can be shortened to: `$("#myDiv").toggleClass("blue myImage red").text('test');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` and `height` properties in `myImage` class were too small for the image to show.

I tried this and it worked:

```
.myImage{
    ...
    width:60px;
    height:70px;
    ...
}​
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/S6Ntn/

Answer (score 0):

The image you are trying to display is 256x256px but the `div` you are using is 6x7px so only a tiny (and transparent) area of it is showing. If you want the whole X to show then you'll either need to resize the image to the correct dimensions, use an `img` tag or use `background-size: 100%` (CSS3 so browser support is limited)

Answer (score 0):

### Update

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6Ssa/43/)
Here is a working sample of using the `img` tag instead of a background. The width and height are still getting set in css, but the `src` is now set within the javascript.

**JavaScript**

```
$("#red").click(red);
$("#blue").click(blue);

function red()
{
    $("#myDiv").removeClass('blue')
        .addClass('red')
        .text('test')
        .remove('img');
}

function blue()
{
      $("#myDiv").removeClass('red')
          .addClass('blue')
          .text('test')
          .append('<img src="http://oneseasonnation.com/www/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/2009/01/ip_icon_02_cancel.png" />');
}
```

**CSS**

```
.red
{
    background-color : red   
}
.blue
{
    background-color : blue   
}
.blue img
{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

​

### Original

You're setting it as a background with a fixed width and height. Background image scaling isn't widely supported, so it may be easier to add an image to the `div` with a specified height and width. You'll need to explicitly add it as an `img` tag, using the `append` jQuery method.

Your image **is** getting set, but it's not visible as it's too large, to demonstrate this I've [updated your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6Ssa/34/) with increased widths and heights for the `#myImage` div.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully see, the image is being displayed and css is also being applied. Whenever you click, there's a small gray-ish box in the far right (you need to scroll probably). That's where the image is loaded. AND, you had a typing error. Instead of `addClass('myImage')` you used `removeClass('myImage')`. Besides that, you didn't utilize the powerful feature of chaining. Check out the update code. It's better and it works.